# To get polygon from black pixels in the black&white image

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I have a black&white image that has connected objects. I want to extract a polygon, using the black pixels. I have tried ApproxPoly algorithm over contour pixels but it returns lots of polygons for each blob (white pixel group)
Here is an example image. What I want is the red polygon, however it returns blue ones.

[image]t

Comment: looks like you missed something in the question